# How to find a element based on text several tags deep in Selenium

Tags: html, selenium

All, I,m very new to Selenium and programming in general. I'm stuck on automating a site. I'm needing some help on how I can find and click on a element based on the text several tags into the html code.

I'm looking for the element that has the text `TEXT DISPLAYED IN BROWSER` in the following HTML code. I can locate the element if I use "find element by id" on
`<div id="appt-24175027" class="grid-row pointer">`, but the problem is the ID `appt-24175027` changes dynamically.

In the HTML code I am looking for the following...

```
1st ELEMENT/TEXT DISPLAYED IN BROWSER
2nd ELEMENT / TEXT DISPLAYED IN BROWSER
3rd ELEMENT / Text DISPLAYED IN BROWSER
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<div id="content" class="content">
<div class="grid-container started">
<div id="started-block" class="grid-header pointer">
<div class="grid-header-icon">
<div class="icon-started">
<div class="inner"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="appt-24175027" class="grid-row pointer">
<div class="cell cell-content">
<div class="main-field">
<span style="color:#000000">TASK ACTIVE</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="grid-container pending expanded">
<div id="pending-block" class="grid-header pointer">
<div class="grid-expander">
<div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid-header-icon">
<div class="icon-pending">
<div class="inner"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="grid-header-title">Pending (5)</div>
</div>
<div id="pending-grid" class="grid-body">
<div id="appt-24181299" class="grid-row pointer">
<div class="cell appt-color" style="border-top: 1px solid rgb(255, 244,          0);border-right: 1px solid rgb(204, 177, 0); background: #FFDE00;"></div>
<div class="cell cell-content">
<div class="main-field">
<span style="color:#000000"></span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="appt-24180104" class="grid-row pointer">
<div class="cell appt-color" style="border-top: 1px solid rgb(255, 244,   0);border-right: 1px solid rgb(204, 177, 0); background: #FFDE00;"></div>
<div class="cell cell-content">
<div class="main-field">
<span style="color:#000000"> 1st ELEMENT/TEXT DISPLAYED IN BROWSER</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="appt-24175024" class="grid-row pointer">
<div class="cell appt-color" style="border-top: 1px solid rgb(255, 224,     168);border-right: 1px solid rgb(204, 163, 122); background: #FFCC99;"></div>
<div class="cell cell-content">
<div class="main-field">
<span style="color:#000000"> 2nd ELEMENT / TEXT DISPLAYED IN BROWSER</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="appt-24175025" class="grid-row pointer">
<div class="cell appt-color" style="border-top: 1px solid rgb(255, 224, 168);border-right: 1px solid rgb(204, 163, 122); background: #FFCC99;"></div>
<div class="cell cell-content">
<div class="main-field">
<span style="color:#000000">3rd ELEMENT / Text DISPLAYED IN BROWSER</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="appt-24175026" class="grid-row pointer">
</div>
```

Comment: Could you tell which element are you looking with using text span or div or anything else??

Comment: As I see your all questions are unaccepted yet while provided answer solved your problem.. you need to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as well if it helped..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using xpath you can simply locate `<div class="grid-row pointer">` using inner text as below :

```
//div[@class = 'grid-row pointer' and contains(.,'1st ELEMENT/TEXT DISPLAYED IN BROWSER')]

//div[@class = 'grid-row pointer' and contains(.,'2nd ELEMENT/TEXT DISPLAYED IN BROWSER')]

//div[@class = 'grid-row pointer' and contains(.,'3rd ELEMENT/TEXT DISPLAYED IN BROWSER')]
```

Hope it helps..:)